# adding a doRead() method to an existing socket object

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

is there any way to add a doRead() method to an existing socket object?

the socket needs a doRead method to be able to be passed to twisted's reactor via the addWriter method.

i've tried using the new module's instance method but it doesn't seem to work...

```
>>> c
<socket._socketobject object at 0x7fcb03cc8b40>
>>> c.doRead = new.instancemethod(doRead, c, socket._socketobject)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'doRead'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `new.instancemethod` that's failing here.  It's the fact that you have a `socket._socketobject`, an instance of an extension type, which doesn't have a `__dict__` so cannot be given arbitrary new attributes.

The typical way in which you make one kind of object look like another kind of object is to use wrapping.  Create a new class that has all the methods you want and gets a reference to your socket.  For example:

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, socket, protocol):
        self.socket = socket
        self.protocol = protocol

    def doRead(self):
        try:
            data = self.socket.recv(self.bufferSize)
        except socket.error, se:
            if se.args[0] == EWOULDBLOCK:
                return
            else:
                return main.CONNECTION_LOST
        if not data:
            return main.CONNECTION_DONE
        return self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
```

This is copied straight from Twisted, of course - it is the solution to exactly the problem you are trying to solve. :)

Re-implementing the guts of Twisted might be a useful exercise to make sure you understand how all the pieces work and fit together, but when you get stuck, the Twisted source itself makes a pretty good reference to help you on your way.

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what i ended up doing in the end.  i thought it would be simpler to just add a method into the object rather than create a wrapper, but i guess in this instance it can't be done.  i actually stared at the connection class source for a while, but couldn't figure out what the protocol parameter was, my guess is that it's a protocol object from twisted.internet.protocol?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.  And that's where it sends the data that it actually reads from the network.